# How can refer to external sources?

Tags: pydev

I'm using Eclipse Juno with Pydev 2.7.1, but I would like to import an external folder in order to modify its contents directly from Eclipse's editor (and reciprocally) .

Is that really impossible ?

I've looked at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394031/how-do-you-create-a-pydev-project-from-existing-code), but it did say how to add external files to PYTHONPATH.
I've also found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519327/how-to-define-an-external-source-folder-in-pydevproject) : but I still can't edit the external files :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found it.

Found in the official faq : [How can I import existing projects](http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIimportexistingprojects/sourcesintoPyDev?) (option 1)

1. Create a new PyDev project
2. Says that you don't want default folder for the new project (see screen capture).
3. Select the directory where are the sources you need to modify directly from Eclipse Editor (see screen capture).

[image: Selecting the original files folder]